# how to fix UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel

Tags: discord.js

i gonna make read this channel only
but it error (node:17212) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel

my code

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  if(message.channel.name.includes("Command-only")){
    message.channel.bulkDelete("1", true);
    if(!message.author.bot){
message.channel.send("Test, you say :" + `${message.content}`);
}
}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bot is reading all messages coming to it, including DMs, which do not have names. You should filter out dm channels.

```js
if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
```

Comment: but i have new problem UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined message.channel.name

Comment: You should try debugging. For example `console.log(message.channel)`. Does that show anything when you write your message?